# Laravel 5.6 - One to many relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm learning laravel and php. I have a member object who can have only 1 language option but there is multiple language options to choose from. 
The member object is my main object. I want to test whether I've setup my relationships correctly but don't see the desired result when testing (I should only see the language selected in the language field, not all the column attributes per member as shown below). So this is the output of my show.blade.php file:

[image]

This my show.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', $member->name)

@section('content')
    <h1>Member Details: </h1>
    <p>Name: {{$member->name}}</p>
    <p>Surname: {{$member->surname}}</p>
    <p>ID Nr: {{$member->id_number}}</p>
    <p>Mobile Nr: {{$member->mobile_number}}</p>
    <p>Email: {{$member->email}}</p>
    <p>D.O.B: {{$member->date_of_birth}}</p>
    <p>Language:{{$member->language}}</p>
    <p>Created At: {{$member->created_at}}</p>
    <div class="page-header">
        <a href="{{action('MemberController@edit', $member->id)}}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
    </div>
@endsection
```

This is my languages table migration file:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('member_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('languages', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')->on('members');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('languages', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('languages_member_id_foreign');
        });
        Schema::dropIfExists('languages');
    }
```

This is my members table migration file:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->string('id_number')->unique();
            $table->string('mobile_number');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->date('date_of_birth');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('name');
            $table->dropColumn('surname');
            $table->dropColumn('id_number')->unique();
            $table->dropColumn('mobile_number');
            $table->dropColumn('email');
            $table->dropColumn('date_of_birth');
        });
    }
```

And lastly my member model:

```
class Member extends Model
{
    public function language() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Language');//('Language') = name of the Language Model
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the JSON representation of the object is because that's all you're asking for in your code when you put `{{$member->language}}`. This represents the entire `App\Language` object.

Try using `{{$member->language->first()->name}}` instead to specify that you are asking for only the `name` variable of the object.

In order to show **all** languages, you'll need to loop through the `$member->language` collection using:

```
@foreach ($member->language as $language)
    {{ $language->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for that. When I add the name as specified above in my show file, I get the following error: "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: G:\laragon\www\tomcrud\resources\views\members\show.blade.php)". The name column is however specified in my languages table?

Comment: My mistake. Try `{{$member->language->first()->name}}`. You are dealing with a collection and need to get the first result (even if there is only one result) before trying to use an object from it.

Comment: Isn't my table structure all wrong? If a member can have only 1 language but 1 language can have many members, shouldn't I 1) drop the member_id column in the language table and 2) add a language_id in the member table? 3) And also I'll have to define the relationship in the Language model? According to laravel docs it seems like the foreign key is automatically defined. Is this correct?

Comment: I think it would be more useful to use a many-to-many relationship using a pivot table so that a language can be spoken by multiple people and people can be multilingual.

Comment: Background: I'm busy with a laravel CRUD test that would allow me to join our dev team if I pass. One of the requirements of this test is that a member can have only 1 language selected from multiple language options. So I need to move within these constraints.

Comment: In that case, yes, your previous comment is correct about the structure. Laravel can automatically figure out the foreign key from the table names unless you're using a custom one.